# Вывод некоторых страниц modx

Tags: modx, меню

```
[[*id:eq=`1`:or:eq=`4`:then=`[[$onas]]`]]
```

Меню выводится только на первой и на четвертой странице, а мне нужно что б выводилась на каждой 1,2,3,4

если ставлю and  вместо or то пропадает совсем.

Общая суть в том что есть страница "О нас" (родительская) в ней страницы 1новость 2новость 3ноовость

Мне нужно что б меню "1новость 2новость 3 новость" работало только на всех этих страницах

[image: Страница О нас в ней пункы меню]

И вот надо что б меню Выводилось только на странице "О нас" и на всех ее вложенных...Кто такой зависимый ..и т.д.

А на других страницах этого меню небыло

Comment: еще раз можно, для каких ID выводить, а для каких - нет?

Comment: Добавил информации

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте модификатор `in`:

```
[[*id:in=`1,2,3,4`:then=`[[$onas]]`]]
```

[Условные модификаторы вывода](https://docs.modx.com/current/ru/building-sites/tag-syntax/output-filters)